# What is the best way to implement Django-Oscar Shipping Methods as model instances?

Tags: python, django, django-oscar, marketplace, shipping-method

I am struggling to understand some concepts that django-oscar implements, regarding shipping, and hope that someone on here can give me some clarity.

I'm trying to understand why the shipping methods are hard-coded classes versus dynamic models, and if I create models for the shipping methods, will it break the get_available_shipping_methods() method?

I have looked through the docs and there are examples explaining how to create new shipping methods by subclasses, but this is not what I am looking for.

I am using django-oscar as the foundation for a marketplace, therefore there will be multiple sellers/shops. I want them to be able to define their own shipping methods, as well as use the "built-in" Shipping methods used to calculate multiple shipping carrier rates.